# Showing only current index polygon extent in Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages

I am currently working on putting together a few map series in Data Driven Pages. I can't figure how to only show the index layer outline for the current page. I would like to hide the outline for any index polygon that is not the current focus of the data frame.

In the example picture below, the first page of my series (index layer is the yellow polygon labelled 1), I would like to hide the index polygon for page 2 (the yellow box in the upper right of the image). As I move on to page two, I would like to hide the index polygon for pages 1 and 3, as all of index polygons adjoin and are sequential.

[image: is it possible to hide non-focus index layers in DDP?]

Is there something simple I am missing or a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to add the index layer to your map document twice.

Use the first instance as the index for your data-driven pages, but don't display it on the map.

Use the second instance to display the outline as you want (i.e. yellow outline), then go into Layer Properties -> Definition Query -> Page Definition. Then check 'Enable', and select the attribute that is being used as your index, then show features that match.

[image: example]