# Exporting 3 layers together as JPEG using Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages, data-frame

I'm trying to use data driven pages to export JPEGs of features that share a common attribute.

E.g. I have two point layers, "beach" and "light". And a polyline that connects them, called "vector".

Each of these features has a common field "Waypoint". I want to export a JPEG of all 3 layers at once that have the same waypoint value, e.g. "1".

The problem that I am encountering is that data driven pages are focused on one "index" layer. So I need to try to figure out the logic to use in ArcPy to overcome this.

Any suggestions?

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013432

Comment: Generate an index layer, then use that.  Either that, or write your own driver.

Comment: Got it, wasn't too clear on how data driven pages worked before. So now all 3 layers print, and I used Page Definition queries for the 2 point layers, but the problem is now that I can still see the other features in the index layer but I want to filter those like I did with the other 2 layers. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If your question has been refined then please use the [edit] button beneath it to revise it to make what you are now asking clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Vince was correct, set polyline as my index layer. Made a copy of the index layer and used it to use Page Definition queries.

Credit:

[How do I only show current index polygon extent in Data Driven Pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199670/how-do-i-only-show-current-index-polygon-extent-in-data-driven-pages)